# Move base coordinates Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to move the coordinates on a tkinter canvas so that the bottom left corner is `(0, 0)`, meaning that the top right corner is `(height, width)`.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to write a function that inverts your vertical coordinate, given the canvas height and desired element height passed in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll have to do math on all of your coordinates to translate them from one coordinate system to another.